# spark container get killed by yarn

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I have a huge dataset of 675GB parquet file with snappy compression and i have to join it with 4 , 5 tables with size like 10 GB . I have a cluster of 500+ nodes each having 128GB ram, but i can only run a executor atmost 28 GB otherwise yarn does not allocate memory.
Please advice how should i procced with this scenario.
Currently i am running pyspark 1.6 and i am only runnning 1 executor per node with 26 Gb ram.
But if i am running the whole join in hive it takes time but get completes.
How should i use my cluster effeciently and procces with this join in spark

Thanks
sPradeep

Answer (score 1):

You should try to increase `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions`, which is by default 200. This parameter controlls the number of partitions (and thus tasks) when doing shuffling (e.g. during joins, groupBy etc). Try a value of 5000 and see if it works.

Comment: I tried with 4000 but it failed again. If i am correct spark.sql.shuffle.partitions make my shuffle rdd to convert into 4000 partition after shuffle no maters how many partition both tables have.